# Using one MediaCapture in multiple CaptureElement.Source

Tags: c#, uwp, c++-cx

I'm trying to preview one MediaCapture to multiple(2) CaptureElement's. For example I have one big CaptureElement and one mini - map of it in the screen corner. Is it possible?

When I'm trying to set initialized Capture to one CaptureElement, everything works fine, but when I share it in 2 places, I'm getting error like "unsupported operation for current state".

Here's the code example, I'm trying to use:

```
await video.TryStopPreviewingAsync();
minimap.Source = null;
await minimap.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
    minimap.Source = video.Stream.Capture;
});
await video.TryStartPreviewingAsync();
```

`minimap` is second CaptureElement,`video.Resources.First.Stream.Capture` is currently previewing capture.

`TryStop/StartPreviewingAsync`calls `Capture.Stop/StartPreviewingAsync()`

I tried to stop previewing first capture, set it like a source in 2 places and then starts previewing on both captureelements, but I got error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm getting error like "unsupported operation for current state".

It's by design, and it will throw exception when pass the `Capture` to multiple `CaptureElement`.

For your scenario, the better way is use image control replace `CaptureElement`, and process frame with `MediaFrameReader`, and then generate bitmap for each frame within [`FrameArrived`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.frames.mediaframereader.framearrived?view=winrt-22000).

And here is [official code sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/CameraFrames) that you could refer to.

Comment: I'm using custom video effects, thats why CaptureElement is prefferable. As I know MediaFrameReader cant be processed on GPU. CaptureElement and IBasicVideoEffect with SupportedMemoryTypes = MediaMemoryTypes.Gpu can be executed on GPU

Comment: Yep, you are right, but you could also make video effect with `MediaFrameReader` that editing softwareBitmap. if you do want to make multiple  CaptureElement , I'd suggest you submit a feedback/feature request about this API/feature in the Feedback Hub. You could find the Feedback Hub in the Start Menu. Please select **Developer Platform**->**API Feedback** as the category when you submit your request. The related team will check the request.